# Delete "unidentified" carriage-return char from a text file

Tags: batch, find-and-replace, special-characters, carriage-return

I have a text file containing a strange *"carriage return"* char.

If I open the file with *Notepad* I **can't** see the new line.

If I open the file with *Wordpad* I **can** see the new line.

I uploaded an example of my file here --> [file.txt (200 byte)](http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=1005552)

I need an automatic way to delete this char from my files. Thak you

Comment: Are you typing these files from scratch or are you copy and pasting the text from elsewhere into Wordpad? To the best of my knowledge, Wordpad does not allow you to use "Find & Replace" on non-printing characters, so you'd need to do this manually. Alternatively, (assuming you do not have Word since you're using Wordpad) you could download Notepad++ (free text editor) which will allow you to use the Find/Replace method to get rid of them.

Comment: standard fayre if you move files from Mac to PC. Notepad just can't cope.

Comment: Word doesn't allow me to modify that char. Notepad++ is perfect and let me do all the work. Solved. Thank you.

Comment: You should post this as the answer to your question to benefit future visitors with your same question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Using the free program **Notepad++** I can *"Find & Replace"* all the unwanted carriage return chars. 
It can olso process all files together.